# Фиксированный min-height у родителя и height: 100% у потомка

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

[Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/vdeKY/10/), в хроме или опере попробуйте изменять размер окна.
Получается, что потомок плюет на минимальную высоту родителя и каким-то кривым образом считает ее из предполагаемой высоты родителя, которая без `min-height` равна высоте окна. Есть какие-то методы борьбы с таким поведением, кроме как указания `min-height` всем узлам с высотой в процентах?

Answer (score 1):

При резиновой верстке желательно указывать элементам min-width и min-height.